# Verifying Android app links fails with error 1024

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app with applicationId `com.unibeam.passkey1`.

At `https://unibeam.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json`, I have stored the following file:

```
[{
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "web",
    "site": "https://unibeam.github.io"
  }
 },
 {
  "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
  "target": {
    "namespace": "android_app",
    "package_name": "com.unibeam.passkey1",
    "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
      "55:E2:84:F9:9B:59:82:02:FA:2B:87:B9:90:77:8F:8D:62:3F:32:CC:76:92:47:0C:A8:73:7C:AE:11:8D:B6:0C",
      "0E:67:51:BF:E4:C4:01:7F:CB:7D:4C:1E:02:7E:DF:8D:40:25:9A:5C:20:2A:AB:96:71:15:F1:46:40:09:58:3D"
    ]
  }
 }]
```

The 2 fingerprints correspond to the debug and release versions of the app.

And checking at `https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://unibeam.github.io&relation=delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds` returns no error.

Now inside the app's `manifest.xml`, I have the following:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:host="unibeam.github.io" />
</intent-filter>
```

The problem is that when running `adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur com.unibeam.passkey1` it fails as follows:

```
  com.unibeam.passkey1:
    ID: 24defbad-89a3-46d4-8446-335dfcdcd0a9
    Signatures: [0E:67:51:BF:E4:C4:01:7F:CB:7D:4C:1E:02:7E:DF:8D:40:25:9A:5C:20:2A:AB:96:71:15:F1:46:40:09:58:3D]
    Domain verification state:
      unibeam.github.io: 1024
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Disabled:
          unibeam.github.io
```

Why does it fail? Does the app need to be on PlayStore for all this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two parts to your question:

**GETTING APP LINKS WORKING**

For this you need the assetlinks.json file to contain entries like this, as described in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing#associatesite). A code example of mine uses these settings:

```json
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.authsamples.basicmobileapp",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "62:7D:06:B1:01:C6:2F:04:9A:D4:5D:17:DF:FF:AB:65:13:8E:E0:CC:F6:60:2A:F6:3A:DA:1D:19:0A:F9:DF:15"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

This does not require deployment to the App Store. You can verify this by running my [example app](https://authguidance.com/basicandroidapp-execution/), which registers deep links when it is installed. My app uses a similar [manifest file](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml#L68) to yours. If you run the app on an emulator, and then this command:

```bash
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur
```

You will see output like this, without the 1024. Further infrastructure details in [this blog post](https://authguidance.com/android-infrastructure-setup/) of mine.

```
 com.authsamples.basicmobileapp:
    ID: 07f8ee96-dc1c-4df0-a7d7-2e9738902088
    Signatures: [62:7D:06:B1:01:C6:2F:04:9A:D4:5D:17:DF:FF:AB:65:13:8E:E0:CC:F6:60:2A:F6:3A:DA:1D:19:0A:F9:DF:15]
    Domain verification state:
      mobile.authsamples.com: verified
    User 0:
      Verification link handling allowed: true
      Selection state:
        Disabled:
          mobile.authsamples.com
```

**GETTING WEBAUTHN / PASSKEY NATIVE LOGINS WORKING**

This is a newer feature, to use [FIDO capabilities](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps), and requires additional registrations like these:

```json
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://mobile.authsamples.com"
    }
  }
]
```

It also requires a couple of steps to specify `asset_statements` within the app, as explained in the link.

**YOUR QUESTION**

In your case, passkey registration looks fine, and you can proceed with implementing passkey logins for users. What is confusing about your question is that you are looking at app link registration details. These will not work unless you include the `handle_all_urls` value.

To progress your setup, I would update to an assetlinks.json of this form, as suggested in the link. Even though your focus may be passkey logins, it makes sense these days for any mobile app to have support for deep linking, even if you don't use it initially.

```json
[
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "com.authsamples.basicmobileapp",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "62:7D:06:B1:01:C6:2F:04:9A:D4:5D:17:DF:FF:AB:65:13:8E:E0:CC:F6:60:2A:F6:3A:DA:1D:19:0A:F9:DF:15"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "relation": [
      "delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls",
      "delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"
    ],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "web",
      "site": "https://mobile.authsamples.com"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but you're wrong. The "delegate permission" must be "common.get_login_creds", according to https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys

Comment: Ah - your question confused me, since it mentions app links in the title. You want to use recent native WebAuthn / passkey support it seems. My company did some work in this area recently. I will update my answer and have a dig around, tomorrow if I get time. I think you are right and [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps) which says handle_all_urls is needed, is now out of date.

Comment: Thank you @Gary Archer and sorry for the confusion in my title.

Comment: FYI, I created a follow-up question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578743/unable-to-register-for-authentication-using-passkey-on-android

Answer (score 1):

The Error code of 1024 or greater specifies the custom error code that's specific to the device's verifier.
Lets first understand the result returned by the adb

```
com.unibeam.passkey1:
    ID: 24defbad-89a3-46d4-8446-335dfcdcd0a9
    Signatures: [**]
    Domain verification state:
  line 1->    unibeam.github.io: 1024
  line 2 ->   User 0:
  line 3->    Verification link handling allowed: true
  line 4->    Selection state:
  line 5->      Disabled:
         unibeam.github.io
```

When you ran the command

```
adb shell pm get-app-links --user cur com.unibeam.passkey1
```

Line 1 represent the domain verification process. Any other state than **"verified"** represent the domain couldn't not be performed.For complete list that domain verification can return is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-android-applinks#invoke-domain-verification).
For the error 1024, make sure you have enabled internet connection and re-invoke the domain verification process.

Line 2 represent the user 0 has manually approved the app in the system settings

Line 3 represent the user 0 has approved unibeam.github.io link

Line 4 represent the all app links that are enabled and disabled.

Line 5 represent the Disabled app links ;here unibeam.github.io is in disabled state.

To manually invoke domain verification process for an app that's installed on a device use the following procedure but you need android 12 for this
Make sure you have enabled internet connection
run the following command in a terminal window

```
adb shell am compat enable 175408749 PACKAGE_NAME
```

Reset the state of android app links on a device, run the following command in a terminal window

```
adb shell pm set-app-links --package PACKAGE_NAME 0 all
```

Then invoke the domain verification process , run the following command

```
adb shell pm verify-app-links --re-verify PACKAGE_NAME
```

Before you review the result of this command, wait a few minutes for the verification agent to finish the request.
For review result ,run the following command

```
adb shell pm get-app-links PACKAGE_NAME
```

I have noticed that your site ended with . (with the trailing period) make sure that route ended with . servers the same content as without. for Example :
"site": "https://unibeam.github.io."
must serve the same content by
"site": "https://unibeam.github.io"

Common erros :
Make sure you have setup the correct intent filter
Make sure server's json configuration and sha value is correct.
Make sure there is no redirects from server side

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is not adding something new to me. Besides, I don't understand what you mean by "I have noticed that your site ended with ." Where do you see that exactly?

Comment: The link you gave https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://unibeam.github.io&relation=delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds

Comment: Ah, I see. This seems to be a strange artifact produced by the verification page at googleapis.com. The source you should look at is here: https://unibeam.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json