# Unable to register for authentication using Passkey on Android

Tags: java, android, webauthn, fido, passkey

I'm trying to follow the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/passkeys) to implement Passkey registration. There is also a [codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/credential-manager-api-for-android) demonstrating the topic (note that it works as intended on my Android device.)

I created this [minimal test-case](https://github.com/unibeam/passkey/tree/master/android/Passkey1) available on github, which replicates what's taking place in the codelab, in Java instead of Kotlin.

```
private void signUp() {
    CreatePublicKeyCredentialRequest createPublicKeyCredentialRequest = new CreatePublicKeyCredentialRequest(fetchRegistrationJsonFromServer());

    credentialManager.createCredentialAsync(
            createPublicKeyCredentialRequest,
            this,
            new CancellationSignal(),
            getMainExecutor(),
            new CredentialManagerCallback<CreateCredentialResponse, CreateCredentialException>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CreateCredentialResponse result) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Registration success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CreateCredentialException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Registration failure - " + e.getClass().getName());

                    if (e instanceof CreatePublicKeyCredentialDomException) {
                        // Handle the passkey DOM errors thrown according to the
                        // WebAuthn spec.
                        Log.e(TAG, String.valueOf(((CreatePublicKeyCredentialDomException)e).getDomError()));
                    } else if (e instanceof CreateCredentialCancellationException) {
                        // The user intentionally canceled the operation and chose not
                        // to register the credential.
                    } else if (e instanceof CreateCredentialInterruptedException) {
                        // Retry-able error. Consider retrying the call.
                    } else if (e instanceof CreateCredentialProviderConfigurationException) {
                        // Your app is missing the provider configuration dependency.
                        // Most likely, you're missing the
                        // "credentials-play-services-auth" module.
                    } else if (e instanceof CreateCredentialUnknownException) {
                    } else if (e instanceof CreateCustomCredentialException) {
                        // You have encountered an error from a 3rd-party SDK. If
                        // you make the API call with a request object that's a
                        // subclass of
                        // CreateCustomCredentialRequest using a 3rd-party SDK,
                        // then you should check for any custom exception type
                        // constants within that SDK to match with e.type.
                        // Otherwise, drop or log the exception.
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}

private String fetchRegistrationJsonFromServer() {
    String response = Utils.readFromAssets(this, "reg.txt");

    return response.replace("<userId>", getEncodedUserId())
            .replace("<userName>", username)
            .replace("<userDisplayName>", username)
            .replace("<challenge>", getEncodedChallenge());
}

private String getEncodedUserId() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);

    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING);
}

private String getEncodedChallenge() {
    SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[32];
    random.nextBytes(bytes);

    return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE | Base64.NO_PADDING);
}
```

Currently, it fails with a `CreatePublicKeyCredentialDomException` of type `androidx.credentials.exceptions.domerrors.SecurityError`.

Note that my app is handling *Digital Asset Links* properly, according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/identity/fido/android/native-apps). Please refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76507667/verifying-android-app-links-fails-with-error-1024) for reference.

Currently, the only part which looks problematic to me is the [registration template](https://github.com/unibeam/passkey/blob/master/android/Passkey1/app/src/main/assets/reg.txt#L4). I tried to replace the "rp.id" value with `com.unibeam.passkey1` but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question... The solution was pretty logical:

Using `unibeam.github.io` as "rp.id" in the registration template. Only this way, the underlying system is able to discover `https://unibeam.github.io/.well-known/assetlinks.json`!

Note that is absolutely not documented, as if Google doesn't want people to implement passkey authentication.